# Collection type form symfony2 display empty inputs in twig

Tags: php, jquery, forms, symfony

I'm writing a symfony2 form with collection type. The form has a field date where the user fills a date and press in a search button with jquery submit the form and refresh the html code with the response and the registers of the select date. My problem is that the form render the inputs well with the number of registers of the query with doctrine of the select date of the user but is all empty and not load the data.

I have two events PRE_SET_DATA and PRE_SUBMIT.
I try with a basic example too but with a equal result.
Thanks and regards.

The forms:

```
 $builder->add('description');
    $builder->add('fecha', DateTimeType::class,array(
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'input'  => 'datetime',
                'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy H:m',
                'html5' => false,
                'label' => "Fecha y hora"
    ));

$builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();
                $asistencia = $event->getData();

                if(!is_null($asistencia->getFecha())){
                    $form->add('tags', CollectionType::class, array(
                        'entry_type' => AsistenciaRegistrosTiempoType::class,
                    ));
                }else {
                    $form->add('tags', CollectionType::class, array(
                        'entry_type' => AsistenciaRegistrosTiempoType::class
                    ));

                }
});


$builder->get('fecha')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm()->getParent();
                // this would be your entity, i.e. SportMeetup
                $data = $event->getData();
                $asistencia = $form->getData();
                if(!is_null($data)){
                    $fecha = new \DateTime($data);
                    $array = new ArrayCollection();
                    $tag1 = new Tag();
                    $tag1->setName('tag1 '.$fecha->format("Y-m-d"));
                    $array->add($tag1);
                    $form->add('tags', CollectionType::class, array(
                        'entry_type' => AsistenciaRegistrosTiempoType::class,
                        'data'=> $array
                    ));

                } else {
                    $form->add('tags', CollectionType::class, array(
                        'entry_type' => AsistenciaRegistrosTiempoType::class,
                    ));
                }
            });
}
```

Form with collection:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
$builder->add('name','text');
}
```

Class of the first form:

```
 class Asistencia
  {
    private $fecha;

    protected $description;

    protected $tags;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFecha()
    {
        return $this->fecha;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $fecha
     */
    public function setFecha($fecha)
    {
        $this->fecha = $fecha;
    }

    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }


    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }

    public function  addTag($tag){
        $this->tags->add($tag);

        return $this;
    }


    public function  setTags($tag){
        $this->tags = $tag;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Class of the second form:

```
class Tag
{
    private $name;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        ladybug_dump("Get ".$this->name);
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        ladybug_dump("Set ".$this->name);
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Action:

```
$formAsistenciaTiempo = $this->createForm(
            new AsistenciaType(),
            $asistenciaTiempo,
            array(
                'action' => $this->generateUrl('dashboard'),
                'method' => 'POST',
            ));


        $formAsistenciaTiempo->handleRequest($request);

        //if ($formAsistenciaTiempo->isSubmitted()) {
            $tab = 2;
            if ($formAsistenciaTiempo->isValid()) {
.......
```

Twig:

```
       {{ form_start(formAsistencia) }}
    {# render the task's only field: description #}
    {{ form_row(formAsistencia.description) }}
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_label(formAsistencia.fecha) }}
                    <div class="input-group date" id='fechahora'>
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        {{ form_widget(formAsistencia.fecha) }}
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="buscar_registros"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Obtener registros</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    <h3>Tags</h3>
    <ul class="tags">
        {# iterate over each existing tag and render its only field: name #}
        {{ formAsistencia.tags | length }}

        {% for tag in formAsistencia.tags %}

            {{ tag |ladybug_dump }}
            {#<li>{{ form_row(tag.name) }}</li>#}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
            {{ form_rest(formAsistencia) }}
{{ form_end(formAsistencia) }}

  <script>
  var $sport = $('#asistencia_fecha');
  // When sport gets selected ...
 $("#buscar_registros").click(function() {
  // ... retrieve the corresponding form.
  var $form = $(this).closest('form');
  // Simulate form data, but only include the selected sport value.
  var data = {};
  data[$sport.attr('name')] = $sport.val();
  // Submit data via AJAX to the form's action path.
  $.ajax({
    url : $form.attr('action'),
    type: $form.attr('method'),
    data : data,
    success: function(html) {
      // Replace current position field ...
      $('.tags').replaceWith(
        // ... with the returned one from the AJAX response.
        $(html).find('.tags')
      );
      // Position field now displays the appropriate positions.
    }
  });
   });
   </script>
```

Comment: You should try to pass the whole form in the ajax request. You can set data as `data: $form.serialize()`

Comment: Thanks Heah for your reply, but I need only pass one var because if I submit all the form, then is valid and only I need the data that will generate after submit the value like a search.